# Is this how you return values in Erlang?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I saw a code for recursion that calculates factorial:

```
-module(helloworld). 
-export([fac/1,start/0]). 

fac(N) when N == 0 -> 1; 
fac(N) when N > 0 -> N*fac(N-1). 

start() -> 
   X = fac(4), 
   io:fwrite("~w",[X]).
```

Is it the way a function returns values in Erlang? by writing right arrow (`->`) and the int value? Speaking about this line:

```
fac(N) when N == 0 -> 1;
```

So it means when N is 0 the function returns 1? or what exactly does it mean when you simply write an int without any words before

Comment: The arrow separates the head of the function, which contains the parameter variables, from the body of the function.  A function returns the value of the last expression that was evaluated, so, yes, fac() returns 1 when N==0.  In the case of the start() function, the last expression that gets evaluated is io:fwrite(), which returns `ok`.  As a side effect, io:fwrite() outputs some text.

Comment: Don't spend time guessing, [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good!](http://learnyousomeerlang.com) can be read for free.